# Dividing table elements by column sums for multiple tables

Tags: r, probability

Can I sweep a list of tables to get conditional probabilities or must I sweep each table individually? Here are some data I just made up, along with the table outputs, to demonstrate my problem

```
positions <- c("forward", "midfield", "defence", "goalkeeper", rep("forward", 5), "defender")
nationality <- c(rep("IRE", 3), "GER", "ITA", "ENG", "FRA", "BRA", "SCO", "ESP")
teams <- c("Milan", "Juventus", "Lazio", "Palermo", "Milan", "Juventus", "Chievo", "Siena", "Parma", "Napoli")



dF <- data.frame(Team = factor(teams),
                 Position = factor(positions), 
                 Nationality = factor(nationality), 
                 stringsAsFactors = T) 

t1 <- t(table(dF$Nationality, dF$Position))
t2 <- t(table(dF$Nationality, dF$Team))



              BRA ENG ESP FRA GER IRE ITA SCO
  defence      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
  defender     0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
  forward      1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
  goalkeeper   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
  midfield     0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0



            BRA ENG ESP FRA GER IRE ITA SCO
  Chievo     0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
  Juventus   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
  Lazio      0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
  Milan      0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
  Napoli     0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
  Palermo    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
  Parma      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
  Siena      1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What I need to do is divide each table entry by the sum of its column in order to get conditional probabilities. I know I can use the sweep function applied to each table but I was wondering whether it can be applied to a list of tables via lapply or through a for loop? I have tried both with no success. I also tried the sweep function with no success.

For example:

```
tbl_list <- list(t1, t2)

for(tbl in tbl_list) {
  tbl <- sweep(tbl, 2, colSums(tbl), `/`)
}
```

Comment: It works well thank you. What exactly is happening with the two functions that you defined in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables are in a list, you may be able to use `sapply` to loop over them as follows

```
sapply(tbl_list, function(y) apply(y, 2, function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

We will loop over the elements of `tbl_list` with `sapply(tbl_list` and apply `function(y)` to them. Each element (`t1` and `t2`) will successively become `y` and undergo `function(y)` which is `apply(y, 2, function(x) x/sum(x))`. Inside `apply`, we will apply `function(x)` to the `MARGIN` `2` (columns). `function(x)` basically divides each element of the columns of `y` with the sum of respective column.

Comment: Okay. It's clearer to me now. Well explained and thank you again.